# Multiple sums with different calculations mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

maybe someone can help me. I have the following table in mongodb and I need to perform the following calculation:
Odds:
**High**
**Average**
**Low**

For each probability, a multiplier must be applied
Example:
**High probability:** Value * 0.87
**Average probability:** Value * 0.5
**Low Probability:** Value * 0.06

I made the following query in the db mongo, but I can apply only one multiplier. I was unable to differentiate each probability to multiply by the above values.

```
db.teste.aggregate(
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {
                    "converted_fields.Probabilidade de fechamento": {
                        $ne: null
                    },
                    "current.value": {
                        $ne: 0
                    },
                    "current.add_time": {
                        $gte: ISODate("2020-07-01")
                    },
                    
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "___group": {
                "probabilidade": "$converted_fields.Probabilidade de fechamento"
            },
            "current___value": "$current.value"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$___group",
            "count": {
                $sum: "$current___value"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "probabilidade": "$_id.probabilidade",
            "valor": {
                $multiply: ["$count", 0.5]
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Result:

```
{   
Alta  - 379,5
Média - 1647,9
Baixa - 3763,32  
}
```

how do I separate a different multiplier for each probability?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `valor` field?

Comment: I would like for each probability result to multiply. Example: The first value has to multiply by 0.87, the second by 0.5 and the third by 0.06. But there in the query I can only do a single multiplication. Did you understand? @MontgomeryWatts

Comment: Is `Média` equal to `valor * 0.5` or  `$count * 0.5`?

Comment: Is Média equal to `valor * 0.5`. The `Alta` value must be multiplied by `0.87` and not by 0.5
@MontgomeryWatts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregation might look something like this:

```
db.teste.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "converted_fields.Probabilidade de fechamento": {
            $ne: null
          },
          "current.value": {
            $ne: 0
          },
          "current.add_time": {
            $gte: ISODate("2020-07-01")
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$converted_fields.Probabilidade de fechamento",
      count: { $sum: "$current.value"}
    }
   },
   {
     $project:
     {
       _id: 1,
       valor:
       {
         $switch:
         {
           branches: [
             {
               case: { $eq: [ "$_id", "Alta"] },
               then: { $multiply: ["$count", 0.87] }
             },
             {
               case: { $eq: [ "$_id", "Médica"] },
               then: { $multiply: ["$count", 0.5] }
             },
             {
               case: { $eq: [ "$_id", "Baixa"] },
               then: { $multiply: ["$count", 0.06] }
             }
           ],
           default: 0
         }
       }
     }
   },
   {
     $group: {
       _id: null,
       probabilidades: {
         $push: {
           k: "$_id",
           v: "$valor"
         }
       }
     }
   },
   {
     $replaceRoot: {
       newRoot: {
         $arrayToObject: "$probabilidades"
       }
     }
   }
 ])
```

The first `$match` stage is still as you had it. In my solution the first `$group` stage will return documents of this form:

```
{
  _id: 'Alta',
  count: 100
}
```

In the following `$project` stage, I use the [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator in order to determine what to multiply `count` by in order to get the correct `valor`. Using the sample document I showed before, this stage will return documents that look like this:

```
{
  _id: 'Alta',
  valor: 87
}
```

Next is another `$group` stage, where I group all of the probability documents together, and push them into an array. The document from this stage might look like this:

```
{
  _id: null,
  probabilidades: [
    { 'k': 'Alta', 'v': 87 },
    { 'k': 'Baixa', 'v': 6 }
  ]
}
```

In the final stage, [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/), I use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to turn the `probabilidades` array into your desired output.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything worked. Only one note in the code is that the name `Média`a is misspelled. It is written `Médica`. Thanks